# Revealing form fields after checkbox is checked django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Im trying to create a form in which, when a user checks the box, the form shows more values to input.

For example, I have the following

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    example_name = forms.charField(label='Name here')
    custom_message_check = forms.booleanField(required=False, initial=False)
    custom_message = forms.charField(label='Custom message here')
```

Is it there a way to make `custom_message` field appear only when `custom_message_check` is activate? I read django docs and didnt find a `widget` for this, can this be done with django or do I need to create a custom html form?

EDIT: Forgot to clarify that the form rendering is being handled with django `{{form.as_p}}`

Answer (score 0):

In your template
do try

```
<p id="custom_message"></p>

var checkbox = document.getElementById("custom_message_check");
var custom_message= document.getElementById("custom_message");

checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        custom_message.innerHtml = "{{ custom_message }}";
    } else {
        custom_message.innerHtml = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm currently rendering the form with `{{form.as_p}}`. Do I need to reder the form in a more classic way or can this be added with the `as_p` function?